# Correctness of use induction in the proof

Tags: induction, convex-analysis, proof-explanation

"Let $S$ be a subset of vector space $V$. Let $P_1, ... , P_n$ be elements of vector space $V$. Let $S$ be the set of all linear combinations $t_1 P_1 + ... t_n P_n$, with $0 \le t_i$ and $t_1 + ... t_n = 1$. Show that S is convex."
To prove that I used induction on number of elements. However, I had an argue with my teacher that says that my proof does not prove the statement in the task, but rather something else. After a long discussion, we didn't manage to understand each other. Could you point me, why use of induction is incorrect here?

Comment: You haven't posted your proof, so we have to guess.  Induction might not be the preferred method of proof here, you are given a fixed set S which you need to show is convex, perhaps if the question was that any set S which is spanned by some linear combination of vectors, then induction might be used to start with 1 element and on to n.

Comment: @user247608 I see that S is spanned not by some, but all linear combinations of points. But still, why does it mean that S is fixed? Why it is not parameterized on n?

Comment: The fact that your proof was not correct does not mean that there is not a correct proof by induction! :)

Comment: @almagest we agreed with my teacher that proof was correct, but the argue was that I proved not exactly what was required in statement

Comment: I have no idea whether your proof could be fixed. However, it is true that the obvious proof of the result does not use induction.